# iPhone 5 UITableView not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am currently working on an app with many UITableViews, I created the app by testing on an iPhone 6. I recently started testing on other devices, I have noticed on an iPhone 5 that any UITableView that has multiple sections, it will skip section 0 and not display it at all. Although on my iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s it will display perfectly fine. Below is some of the code that is used to display the UITableView for my Profile section. Any help will be greatly appreciated. It is worth mentioning that all the devices are running 9.1. Thanks.

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 2;
    } else if (section == 1) {
        if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"captures"]) {
            if ([_capturesArray count] > 0) {
                return [_capturesArray count];
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"comments"]) {
            if ([_commentsArray count] > 0) {
                return [_commentsArray count];
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"followers"]) {
            if ([_followersArray count] > 0) {
                return [_followersArray count];
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"following"]) {
            if ([_followingArray count] > 0) {
                return [_followingArray count];
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"userCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"menuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"captures"] && [_capturesArray count] > 0) {
            // Get Capture
            Capture *capture = _capturesArray[indexPath.row];

            // Create Cell
            NSString *cellID = capture.cellID;

            CaptureTableViewCells *cell = (CaptureTableViewCells *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

            if (cell == nil) {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CaptureCells" owner:nil options:nil];
                if ([capture.cellID isEqualToString:FeaturedCellID]) {
                    cell = (CaptureTableViewCells *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
                } else {
                    cell = (CaptureTableViewCells *)[nib objectAtIndex:1];
                }
            }

            return cell;
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"comments"] && [_commentsArray count] > 0) {

        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"followers"] && [_followersArray count] > 0) {

        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"following"] && [_followingArray count] > 0) {

        } else {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"emptyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            // Configure the cell...

            return cell;
        }

    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"userCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]) {
        UIImageView *profileImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
        profileImageView.layer.borderColor = [self uicolorFromHex:0xffd700].CGColor;
        profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 5;
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width/2;
        profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    } else if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]) {
        // Get Buttons
        _capturesMenuButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        _commentsMenuButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        _followersMenuButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        _followingMenuButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:4];

        // Set Text Of Buttons
        if ([_capturesArray count] > 0) {
            [_capturesMenuButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[_capturesArray count]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        // Set Buttons Selector
        [_capturesMenuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(capturesMenuButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_commentsMenuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commentsMenuButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_followersMenuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followersMenuButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_followingMenuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followingMenuButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"captures"]) {
            if ([_capturesArray count] > 0) {
                // Has Captures
                CaptureTableViewCells *capCell = (CaptureTableViewCells *)cell;

                // Get Capture At Index
                Capture *capture = _capturesArray[indexPath.row];

                capCell.capture = capture;

                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:capture.captureImage.imageURL];
                UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay"];

                __weak CaptureTableViewCells *weakCell = capCell;

                [capCell.captureImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                                             placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                                                      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                                          weakCell.captureImageView.image = image;
                                                          weakCell.capture.captureImage.image = weakCell.captureImageView.image;
                                                          [weakCell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                                          [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                                                      } failure:nil];
            } else {
                // No Captures
                UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
                label.text = @"You have no Captures.";
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"comments"]) {
            if ([_commentsArray count] > 0) {
                // Has Captures
            } else {
                // No Captures
                UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
                label.text = @"You have no comments.";
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"followers"]) {
            if ([_followersArray count] > 0) {
                // Has Captures
            } else {
                // No Captures
                UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
                label.text = @"You have no followers.";
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"following"]) {
            if ([_followingArray count] > 0) {
                // Has Captures
            } else {
                // No Captures
                UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
                label.text = @"You are not following anyone.";
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove seperator inset
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Setup Style For Cell
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]) {
        return 208;
    } else if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]) {
        return 72;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"captures"]) {
            if ([_capturesArray count] > 0) {
                Capture *capture = _capturesArray[indexPath.row];

                return capture.cellHeight;
            } else {
                return self.view.frame.size.height - 280 - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"comments"]) {
            if ([_commentsArray count] > 0) {
                Capture *capture = _commentsArray[indexPath.row];

                return capture.cellHeight;
            } else {
                return self.view.frame.size.height - 280 - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"followers"]) {
            if ([_followersArray count] > 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return self.view.frame.size.height - 280 - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
            }
        } else if ([_selectedSection isEqualToString:@"following"]) {
            if ([_followingArray count] > 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return self.view.frame.size.height - 280 - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**
So I commented out everything in tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: and just returned 100 for the height of every cell. Now my Section 0 cells are visible. When I added log statements to see what happens this is what i get.

This is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSLog(@"IndexPath: %ld, %ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);
        if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]) {
            NSLog(@"Setting Height");
            return 208;
        }
```

This is my Log:

```
2015-12-14 13:27:21.678 Captures[324:42956] IndexPath: 0, 0
2015-12-14 13:27:21.678 Captures[324:42956] IndexPath: 0, 1
```

As you can see it skips right over setting the height of Section 0 row 0. On my iPhone 6 and iPhone5s this does not happen. Does anyone know why this would occur?

Comment: did u check the view debugger,if the section is shifted to the very top where you cant see it?

Comment: Are you creating your table view in storyboard or in code? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @Mr.T I can see my Section 0 header at the top of the screen and nothing is under it. It just skips to Section 1. I am not too familiar with the view debugger. I did Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy. Once it was open I clicked "Show clipped content" and as far as I can tell there is nothing above my Section 0 Header.

Comment: @AdeelMiraj I am using Storyboards with Auto Layout.

Comment: Did you try logging the height of each cell?

Comment: Did you try show tableview in Debug View Hierarchy ?

Comment: @AdeelMiraj Yes. This is what I did `NSLog(@"tableView: heightForIndexPath: %d, %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    if (indexPath == [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]) {
        NSLog(@"Setting Height of 0, 0");
        return self.view.frame.size.width / 1.77777777777778;
    }` this is placed just under the start of the method. My log shows `2015-12-14 12:56:20.171 Captures[299:22412] tableView: heightForIndexPath: 0, 0
2015-12-14 12:56:20.171 Captures[299:22412] tableView: heightForIndexPath: 0, 1` as you can see there is no log statement that it set the height.

Comment: However, when i run the same thing on my iPhone 6 it does show that the height is being set.

Comment: Be wary of checking the equality of objects using `==`. What if you change the if statement to read `if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small test app to confirm: you should not use the `==` operator to compare `NSIndexPath`objects like you are in your code. While it does seem to be working on my iPhone 6 simulator, it does NOT work on the iPhone 5 simulator.

Instead of checking whether or not the 2 objects are equal, you should either use the `compare:` method, or check the individual properties of the `NSIndexPath`.

Per Apple's docs, `compare:` seems to be preferred: [Comparing Index Paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexPath/compare:)

```
if([indexPath compare:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]] == NSOrderedSame)
    // do something
```

You can also check the individual properties of the `NSIndexPath` if you don't necessarily care about both the `section` and `row` properties.

```
if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0)
    // do something
```

Comment: Thanks @Stonz2 I made the changes you suggested and it worked great.